# Como excluir un atributo de un SELECT * en SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Tengo un SQL con una tabla principal de donde me traigo la mayoria de los campos, pero entre todos esos campos hay dos que son ***BUSINESS_GROUP*** Y ***CALC_ALT_REGION*** que no quiero que vengan de esa misma tabla sino de otra (la que tengo en el LEFT JOIN) pero a la primera tabla llamo a todos los campos con el M.*

```
select
   ITM.BUSINESS_GROUP_DESC,
   ITM.CALC_ALT_REGION,
   M.*,
from POC_Master M
LEFT JOIN D_ITEM AS ITM
ON M.COMP_ID = ITM.COMP_ID AND M.ITEM = ITM.ITEM
```

No tengo opcion de ver que campos tiene esa tabla principal (M) por razones de accesos y más, por lo que traerme campo por campo no lo veo posible

¿Hay manera de traer solo esos campos de BUSINESS_GROUP_DESC Y CALC_ALT_REGION pero excluyendo estos mismos campos de la tabla principal?

Comment: No hay manera, SQL maneja columnas nombradas y el único comodín es `*`.

Comment: Pon en el `SELECT` las columnas que necesites de manera explícita.

Answer (score 0):

1. Dices que no tienes forma de ver qué campos tiene M por cuestiones de accesos. Pero por lo que comentas, ¿puedes hacer un `SELECT M.* FROM POC_Master M`? Si lo haces, ya tienes todos sus campos (hasta que se cambie la estructura, claro). Así, ya podrías saber cuáles son el resto de campos. Esa sería la respuesta real a tu pregunta.
2. En cualquier caso, puedes hacer `SELECT ITM.BUSINESS_GROUP_DESC AS BUSINESS_GROUP_DESC_ITM` (por ejemplo), y así ya puedes distinguir la columna/campo de una tabla y otra.